# Determine the character of all singularities of function: $g(z)= \frac{1}{e^{z^{2}} -1}.$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

> Determine the character of all singularities of function:
>
> $$g(z)= \frac{1}{e^{z^{2}} -1}.$$

I would say $0$ is a pole, but I don't know how to indicate its order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that $z=0$ is a pole. To find its order use Taylor's expansion for $e^{z^2}$ at $z=0$ and you'll see that the leading term is $z^2$, hence the order of pole $0$ equals to $2$.

Comment: Hi (behind you ;) )

Answer (score 3):

Actually one of the best way to find order of the pole of function kind of $\frac{1}{g(x)}$ - is to find first derivative, which is not equal to zero. In this case:

$g(0) = 0$

$g'(x) = 2e^{z^2}z$, so $g'(0) = 0$

$g''(x) = 2e^{z^2} + 2z^2e^{z^2}$, so $g''(0) = 2$

That's why the order is 2.

Actually, I also wanted to say, that not only z = 0 is singularity. Also $z^2 = 2\pi n i$.

Comment: well, what if the order is $2009$? is computing derivatives still the best way to find the order of a singularity?

Comment: @pointguard0, otherwise you cannot prove it strictly (of course if you not use Loran series). I doubt that you cannot compute derivates of function kind of $x^{2019}$. But derivates is very use-full especially in cases like $\frac{1}{cos(x) -1}$. A lot of people forger that $2\pi n$ is actually second-order pole.